# Sign function whose argument is an element of a group?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, group-theory

Let $G$ be the group of the permutation of $N$ particles, $P\in G$. Therefore, there are $N!$ elements in $G$.  For its subgroup, e.g., even permutation, we can calculate $\text{sign}(P)$ and get $\text{sign}(P)=+1$. Could you please explain the meaning of the the function $\text{sign}(P)$ and the formula as follows

$$P'' = P P' \to \text{sign}(P'') = \text{sign}(P)\text{sign}(P') $$?

PS:  The sign function, in which the argument is a operator,i.e., an element of a group) is hard to me.  As I know the sign function $\text{sign}(x)$ is defined as a function of numbers. That is: the sign function of a real number $x$ is defined as

\begin{align}
\text{sign}(x) = \left\{
      \begin{array}{lr}
          1 & : 0 < x < \infty\\
          0 & : x=0 \\
                        -1 & : -\infty <x<0
        \end{array}
     \right.
\end{align}

Comment: Definition of sign of a permutation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are "elementary" permutations sometimes called **transpositions**, which swap only a pair of elements. e.g.

$$\text{abcde}\to \text{cbade}$$

Every permutation $p$ can be written as a product (composition) of consecutive transpositions.

There are many such decompositions for a fixed permutation. *However, changing the decomposition,  the number of these transpositions is always odd or always even, depending only on the considered $p$*.

This way the **sign of a permutation** $p$ is defined: $\mathrm{sign}(p)=-1$ if $p$ can be decomposed  as an odd number of transpositions, otherwise $sign(p)=1$. With that definition it turns out that $$\mathrm{sign}(pp') =\mathrm{sign}(p)\: \mathrm{sign}(p')\:.$$